# Frequent UDP_IN Blocked for Port Scanning

Tags: ip-blocking, port-scanning

I run a blog self-hosted with Wordpress. I'm getting frequent email notifications from LFD regarding UDP_IN blocks. I usually get 10+ emails daily about it.

The email looks like following:

> Time:
> IP:
> Hits:    11
> Blocked: Temporary Block
>
> Sample of block hits:
> host kernel: Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=x.x.x.x DST=x.x.x.x LEN=xxx TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=xxx ID=xxxxx PROTO=UDP SPT=xxx DPT=xxx LEN=xxx

Almost everytime the blocked IP address is different. I want to know is it some kind of attack or is it a false positive?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the port typically used to negotiate an IPSec VPN, so this is probably a result of bots searching the internet for a misconfigured VPN they can exploit, and/or one with weak security they can hack into.

### [Specifically:](http://www.auditmypc.com/udp-port-500.asp)

> Port Number: 500
>  TCP / UDP: UDP
>  Delivery: No
>   Protocol / Name: isakmp
>  Port Description: isakmp. Used in FW-1
>   VPN for key exchange & synch when using ISAKMP or IPSEC crypto between
>   FW-1′s. FW-1 Ports: tcp 256, tcp/udp 259, udp 500, tcp 900.

So, yes, it's an attack, but no, it's nothing you need to worry about (unless you're running a VPN server from your webserver for some reason).

Comment: ^^ Thanks a lot for your reply. Is there anything which I can do to stop these kind of attacks or should I simply ignore these emails?

Comment: @AnotherBlogger You should get a better system, that only emails you things that are important.

Comment: @AnotherBlogger  Looks like a probably port scan to me.  Like Michael Hampton said, you should get a better system in place to only send you alerts about things that matter.

Comment: ^^ Thanks. Those email alerts were sent by the CSF firewall itself. Is there any recommendation to set it to only send alerts that actually matter?

Comment: @AnotherBlogger  I have no idea how to configure the setting on that product (though I suppose you could ask another question about it here if the documentation' of no help), but you really should strive to eliminate false positives - they have a way of desensitizing the people getting the alerts, and creating false negatives (missed events).